# How to remove class if value of select is selected (option)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm fresh student and soon I will have to finish project. But I'm stuck!
I do learn JS but I can't understand how to make something. So this is what I need to make.

I have select elements with some options. Some divs with select are hidden and I want to show them when someone click on 1st select some option example "Veliki servis". (Want to remove class hidden from #filteri #ulja.) I tried and I am tired now.

Hope will get answer soon so I can analyze.

```js
var velikiservis = document.getElementById("velikiservis");
var maliservis = document.getElementById("maliservis");
var promjenaulja = document.getElementById("promjenaulja");
var dijagnostika = document.getElementById("dijagnostika");
var izmjenaguma = document.getElementById("izmjenaguma");
var tehnicki = document.getElementById("tehnicki");
var autolin = document.getElementById("autolin");
var autoklima = document.getElementById("autoklima");
var autogume = document.getElementById("autogume");
var autoelektrika = document.getElementById("autoelektrika");
var poliranje = document.getElementById("poliranje");

const select = document.getElementById("uslugeSelect");
// const option = select.option[select.selectedIndex];

// console.log(select)

var filteri = document.getElementById("filteri");
var ulja = document.getElementById("ulja");


// console.log(velikiservis.text);
// console.log(filteri.classList.remove("hidden"));
// console.log(filteri);
// console.log(uslugeSelect.value = velikiservis.value);
// console.log(filteri.classList)

// const removeClass = function(){
//  if (select.option = velikiservis.text) {
//      filteri.classList.remove("hidden");
//  } else {
//      filteri.classList.add("hidden");
//  }
// };
// removeClass();
```

```html
<div id="homeContent2">
  <!-- homeContent2 #START -->
  <h1>Pošalji upit!</h1>
  <form method="" action="POST" id="section1Form">
    <input type="text" name="carBrand" id="carBrand" value="" placeholder="Marka auta" required="">
    <select class="section1Select" name="carType" id="carType" required="">
      <option value="Tipovi automobila">Tipovi automobila</option>
      <option value="Sedan (limuzina)">Sedan (limuzina)</option>
      <option value="Kupe">Kupe</option>
      <option value="Hatchback">Hatchback</option>
      <option value="SUV">SUV</option>
      <option value="Crossover">Crossover</option>
      <option value="Minivan">Minivan</option>
      <option value="Pickup">Pickup</option>
      <option value="Karavan">Karavan</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="enginePower" id="enginePower" value="" placeholder="Snaga motora (KW)" required="">
    <input type="text" name="carNumber" id="carNumber" value="" placeholder="Broj šasije" required="">
    <div id="usluge">
      <select class="section1Select" name="uslugeSelect" id="uslugeSelect" required="">
        <option value="" selected>Usluge</option>
        <option id="velikiservis" value="vs">Veliki servis</option>
        <option id="maliservis" value="ms">Mali servis</option>
        <option id="promjenaulja" value="pu">Promjena ulja</option>
        <option id="dijagnostika" value="rd">Računalna dijagnostika</option>
        <option id="izmjenaguma" value="ig">Izmjena guma</option>
        <option id="tehnicki" value="pzt">Pregled za tehnički</option>
        <option id="autolin" value="ap">Auto plin</option>
        <option id="autoklima" value="ak">Auto klima</option>
        <option id="autogume" value="ag">Auto gume</option>
        <option id="autoelektrika" value="ae">Auto elektrika</option>
        <option id="poliranje" value="p">Poliranje</option>
      </select>
      <div id="filteri" class="hidden">
        <select class="section1Select" name="filteriSelect" id="filteriSelect" required="">
          <option selected="selected">Filteri</option>
          <option value="TQ-Tokic">TQ - Tokić</option>
          <option value="Bosch">Bosch</option>
          <option value="Mahle">Mahle</option>
          <option value="Japan Parts">Japan Parts</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <!-- filteri #END -->
      <div id="ulja" class="hidden">
        <select class="section1Select" name="uljaSelect" id="uljaSelect" required="">
          <option value="">Ulja</option>
          <option value="Castrol">Castrol</option>
          <option value="Total">Total</option>
          <option value="Aral">Aral</option>
          <option value="Manol">Manol</option>
          <option value="Neko drugo ulje">Neko drugo ulje</option>
          <input type="text" name="drugaUlja" id="drugaUlja" required="" placeholder="ulje..">
        </select>
      </div>
      <!-- ulja #END -->
    </div>
    <!-- usluge #END -->
    <div id="contctForm" class="section1Select">
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required="" placeholder="Ime i prezime">
      <input type="mail" name="mail" id="mail" required="" placeholder="E-mail">
      <input type="text" name="contactNumber" id="contactNumber" required="" placeholder="Kontakt tel/mob">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<!-- homeContent2 #END -->
```

Comment: You'll need an `onchange` handler on the select element. Only inside there it makes sense to access `select.value` and decide which element to show depending on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a compact way of achieving your objective:

```js
const D={}; // global object for storing references to DOM elements
"usluge,filteri,ulja".split(",").forEach(e=>D[e]=document.getElementById(e+"Select"));
(D.usluge.onchange=ev=>{
  D.filteri.style.display=D.ulja.style.display=ev.target.value==="vs"?"":"none";
})({target:{}}) // the change event handler is called once after definition with the object {target:{}}
```

```html
<div id="homeContent2">
  <!-- homeContent2 #START -->
  <h1>Pošalji upit!</h1>
  <form method="" action="POST" id="section1Form">
    <input type="text" name="carBrand" id="carBrand" value="" placeholder="Marka auta" required="">
    <select class="section1Select" name="carType" id="carType" required="">
      <option value="Tipovi automobila">Tipovi automobila</option>
      <option value="Sedan (limuzina)">Sedan (limuzina)</option>
      <option value="Kupe">Kupe</option>
      <option value="Hatchback">Hatchback</option>
      <option value="SUV">SUV</option>
      <option value="Crossover">Crossover</option>
      <option value="Minivan">Minivan</option>
      <option value="Pickup">Pickup</option>
      <option value="Karavan">Karavan</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="enginePower" id="enginePower" value="" placeholder="Snaga motora (KW)" required="">
    <input type="text" name="carNumber" id="carNumber" value="" placeholder="Broj šasije" required="">
    <div id="usluge">
      <select class="section1Select" name="uslugeSelect" id="uslugeSelect" required="">
        <option value="" selected>Usluge</option>
        <option id="velikiservis" value="vs">Veliki servis</option>
        <option id="maliservis" value="ms">Mali servis</option>
        <option id="promjenaulja" value="pu">Promjena ulja</option>
        <option id="dijagnostika" value="rd">Računalna dijagnostika</option>
        <option id="izmjenaguma" value="ig">Izmjena guma</option>
        <option id="tehnicki" value="pzt">Pregled za tehnički</option>
        <option id="autolin" value="ap">Auto plin</option>
        <option id="autoklima" value="ak">Auto klima</option>
        <option id="autogume" value="ag">Auto gume</option>
        <option id="autoelektrika" value="ae">Auto elektrika</option>
        <option id="poliranje" value="p">Poliranje</option>
      </select>
      <!-- <div id="filteri" class="hidden" >-->
      <select class="section1Select" name="filteriSelect" id="filteriSelect" required="">
        <option selected="selected">Filteri</option>
        <option value="TQ-Tokic">TQ - Tokić</option>
        <option value="Bosch">Bosch</option>
        <option value="Mahle">Mahle</option>
        <option value="Japan Parts">Japan Parts</option>
      </select>
      <!-- </div> -->
      <!-- filteri #END -->
      <!-- <div id="ulja" class="hidden"> -->
      <select class="section1Select" name="uljaSelect" id="uljaSelect" required="">
        <option value="">Ulja</option>
        <option value="Castrol">Castrol</option>
        <option value="Total">Total</option>
        <option value="Aral">Aral</option>
        <option value="Manol">Manol</option>
        <option value="Neko drugo ulje">Neko drugo ulje</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" name="drugaUlja" id="drugaUlja" required="" placeholder="ulje..">
      <!-- /div> -->
      <!-- ulja #END -->
    </div>
    <!-- usluge #END -->
    <div id="contctForm" class="section1Select">
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required="" placeholder="Ime i prezime">
      <input type="mail" name="mail" id="mail" required="" placeholder="E-mail">
      <input type="text" name="contactNumber" id="contactNumber" required="" placeholder="Kontakt tel/mob">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<!-- homeContent2 #END -->
```

I took the liberty of removing the encasing `div`s around the two hidden selects to make them appear directly behid the first `select` but this can be reversed, of course. The script should still work.

The line

```
D.filteri.style.display=D.ulja.style.display=ev.target.value==="vs"?"":"none";
```

is rather condensed. It could be rewritten as

```
let disp = ev.target.value==="vs"?"":"none";
D.filteri.style.display = disp;
D.ulja.style.display = disp;
```

1. The variable `disp` gets set to either `""` or to `"none"`, depending on whether the value of the changed element (the select widget) is `"vs"` or not.
2. The two DOM elements `#filteriSelect` and `#uljaSelect` (references to them are stored in the variables `filteri` and `ulja`) are made visible/invisible by the assignment of the string contained in `disp` to their `.style.display` properties.

My slightly less readable one-liner version helps me avoid setting up the local variable `disp` but both versions should work with the same efficiency.

Comment: Well thanks with ur help i made this without removing divs and it work but on else part doesn't... Else part should do if its not add class again 
selectElement.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  if (velikiservis.text === "Veliki servis") {
   filteri.classList.remove("hidden");
   ulja.classList.remove("hidden");
  } else {
   filteri.classList.add("hidden");
   ulja.classList.add("hidden");
  }
 });

Comment: I changed my code, now the "else" part should work too ...

Comment: Thanks that't work.. now i gonna analyze is so i can understand what happen :D

Comment: I do really want to thank you, so thanks :) you made it clear for me